# Word count for a scrollable JTextArea (scrollPane) word count

Tags: java, jlabel, jtextarea

I have been trying to make a program where data inputted into a JTextArea, would then be counted and then displayed on a JLabel the number of words, after a button is clicked.

However the code I have tried to use, just shows the value of 1 everytime.

Any idea why?
`
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
    import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

```
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class SPanel extends JPanel {

public SPanel(){
    final TextAPanel textPanel = new TextAPanel();

    final JLabel outputLabel = new JLabel();
    JButton click = new JButton ("Click");
    click.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            String word = textPanel.inputBox.getText();

            System.out.println("Test: " +word);

        }

    });

 }
}

  import java.awt.Dimension;
  import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
  import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

 import javax.swing.JLabel;
 import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
public class TextAPanel extends JPanel {
public JTextArea inputBox = new JTextArea(20,10);
public JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(inputBox);
TextAreaPanel(){

    JLabel title = new JLabel("Please type in the box below:");

    inputBox.setLineWrap(true);

    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

    gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 0;

    add(title,gc);

    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 1;
    add(scrollPane, gc);


}

 }
```

Just to put it in context, my JTextArea is on a seperate panel / class to the panel containing the button and JLabel.

Every time I run the program and click the button, after inputting some words the value is always one even if the text box is empty.

Comment: you create `new TextAPanel();` when button clicked .why

Comment: do you mean the textPanel, if so then  its because the textbox is in another class and to access it, I need to make a local variable to then get acess if that makes sense.

Comment: check `System.out.println("".split("\\s+").length);`  is 1 .actually text is empty

Comment: So at the top I have an instance variable : Private TextPanel TextAPanel()

Comment: I do not understand what you mean, can you explain a little.

Comment: you should initialize it only ones .you make new `TextAPanel` every time so there is no text in new field . move initializing step to constructor or a initial method

Comment: Ahh okay that makes sense, so should I just move it somewhere else?

Comment: it depends on your code .basically you should initialize it one time . but you cannot do it inside button action because when you click buton all codes inside button action execute .so there is no time you to input text .

Comment: I have moved it now. The issue still persists though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you create a new `TextAPanel` and assign it to the `textPanel` variable - then when you try to get input you get nothing, because the newly created panel doesn't contain anything. If `textPanel` is a field in your class, you should just remove the `textPanel = new TextAPanel();` line and it should work fine. If you get a NullPointerException, it means you forgot to initialize it earlier in the code, you should probably do it in the constructor.

EDIT: OK, I made it work, the code is below. I have no idea how your program compiled, because in your TextAPanel class you had `TextAreaPanel()` method/constructor, which caused compilation error in my Eclipse. Anyway, I got this working, you'll need to complete it, but this should get you started:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SPanel extends JPanel {

    public SPanel() {
        final TextAPanel textPanel = new TextAPanel();
        this.add(textPanel);

        final JLabel outputLabel = new JLabel();
        JButton click = new JButton("Click");
        click.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                String word = textPanel.inputBox.getText();

                System.out.println("Test: " + word);
                System.out.println(word.split("\\s+").length);
            }

        });

        this.add(click);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.add(new SPanel());
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class TextAPanel extends JPanel {
    public JTextArea inputBox = new JTextArea(20, 10);
    public JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(inputBox);

    TextAPanel() {

        JLabel title = new JLabel("Please type in the box below:");

        inputBox.setLineWrap(true);

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 0;

        add(title, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 1;
        add(scrollPane, gc);

    }

}
```

Comment: I have removed it, I did get a NullPointerException, but I have correctly initialized it now, however the word count is still 1, even when it is blank.

Comment: Well, it's just how split() works - try to run 'String input = "";System.out.println(input.split("\\s+").length);'

Comment: Tried it, still doesn't work. I have used split() before, so I know that I ain't doing it wrong. I think its the conversion, where I get the input from the text box which is the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What I said was that when you try to split an empty string, you get an array of size 1. When your text box is empty and you call `getText()` on it, you get an empty string. When you try to split this string, you get an array of size 1, which is a normal behavior when using split(). I find it strange too, but this is not a bug. If you really care about empty input, you can check if the input is empty before trying to split it.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, it does not work properly when it is blank either, so I think I am doing something wrong within my other code, if it should work.

Comment: From what I can think of, I believe that I may have created another textbox, which is not visible on the interface, and the one that is visible is not being referred to. However I cannot find the error in the code yet.

Comment: Can you post the code for the entire class? To check if you're gerring text from correct textPanel, you can print input to the screen before splitting it.

Comment: I can confirm, I am indeed reffering to a wrong textArea, will update now the class.

Comment: label and button are added at bottom, whereas the textbox is added in the other class

Comment: Can you show what `TextAPanel` is and how you add it to the user interface? That's the critical element of your problem, and the code you've shown only contains initializing `textPanel` with default constructor.

Comment: Right TextAPanel is added like this: c.add(TextAPanel, BorderLayout.WEST); I have also updated the post with theother class

Comment: Check out my main answer, and please accept it if it solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you! , as you can see I don't know much about OOP